# How to make the outer element's width match the width of its contents?

Tags: html, css, width

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>Caption1</li>
        <li>Caption2</li>
        <li>Caption3</li>
        <li>Caption4</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Basically, the list items are positioned on the same line with the ***float:left*** in their style and the ***div*** has a 1px border that encircles the ***ul*** element:

[image]

The only problem, I have to set the width of the outer div manually. If I set the width to a lower value, the content will shrink instead of pushing away the border of the container div:

[image]

Any suggestions how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `div` to have `display: inline-block` (and put it inside another `div` to maintain the original `div`'s block-like attributes)

Comment: Thanks, now I feel stupid :) No really, thank you, inline-block did the job.